# Pronunciación de la letra uve a final de palabra

Tags: pronunciación, préstamo-lingüístico, consonantes, betacismo, cultura-de-masas

Aprovechando que han subido la serie de *Evangelion* a Netflix España con una nueva traducción y doblaje, es el momento de ir planteando aquí algunas preguntas sobre el idioma que dicha serie me está generando. Empezamos con una sencilla.

Un nombre que se repite mucho en la serie es el de la organización Nerv. Al pronunciar este nombre propio se cambia la *v* por una *f*, sonando más como *Nerf*. Aunque claro, la palabra *nerv* está tomada en este caso del alemán (significa *nervio*), y su pronunciación original suena claramente con una *f* final, al menos según el traductor de Google.

Sin embargo, el español tiene al menos dos palabras registradas en el diccionario que acaban con *v*: *[lev](https://dle.rae.es/?id=NC1zIv6)* y *[molotov](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Pb7A9bZ)*. En ambos casos me da la sensación de que la pronunciación de esa *v* final no es la misma que la de la *b* en posición final en palabras como *club*, *baobab* o *esnob*. Pero la RAE parece [dejarlo claro](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=v):

> No existe en español diferencia alguna en la pronunciación de las letras *b* y *v*. Las dos representan hoy el sonido bilabial sonoro /b/.

¿Esto es así incluso cuando las letras van a final de palabra? ¿O tiene la *v* un sonido diferente al de la *b* en dicha posición?

---

Sí, entiendo que *lev* procede del búlgaro y *molotov* del ruso, lo que puede hacer que sus pronunciaciones se vean influenciadas por dichos idiomas, pero la RAE las registra con grafías adaptadas, así que entiendo que deberían pronunciarse con las reglas del español.

Comment: la palabra *lev* no la conocía pero *molotov* para mi se pronuncia claramente \molotof\

Comment: Interesante la pregunta.  En Puebla (zona central de México) oí una variante de "Paseo Bravo" (el nombre de un parque).  Se oyó así: *Paseo Brap*.

Comment: Puedes ver en cierta versión de la obra de Les Luthiers, Oi gadoñaya (publicidad gratuita) como dice el verso '¡Viva el conde de Romanov! / Grita fuerte el locutor en off', lo cual mantiene la rima consonante (o al menos, la disimula bastante bien)

Comment: Yo siempre he escuchado *molotov* como [molo'toβ], es decir, exactamente como se esperaría dado que para todos los propósitos *v* debe pronunciarse como *b*.

Comment: Related meta discussion: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3116/9385

Answer (score 5):

#### Pronunciation of orthographic "-b" vs "-v"

The RAE's [*Ortografía*](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=4057128) states that "v" is conserved word-terminally in some words of Slavic origin for purely etymological reasons, the implication being that there is no general difference in *pronunciation* from those ending "-b":

> **a)** Se emplea *b* en posición final de palabra: *club, esnob* etc. Son excepción los extranjerismos de procedencia eslava *molotov* y *lev*, así como las transcripciones al alfabeto latino de ciertos nombres propios eslavos, ya sean topónimos, como *Kiev*, o antropónimos, como los apellidos que contienen las terminaciones patronímicas *-ev, -ov*: *Prokófiev, Romanov*

#### Pronunciation of word-final /b/

Of the three voiced plosives in Spanish (/b/ /d/ /g/) only /d/ appears natively in word-final position.<sup>7</sup> /b/ is also often reduced to [p] or [β̥˕] when occurring before a voiceless obstruent (e.g. *obtener*).<sup>11</sup> As such, word-final /b/ is often reduced to [p] in loanwords (or omitted altogether). However, due in part to the small number of such loans (< 20), their recent adoption, and to what extent they have been in influenced by the original orthography or pronunciation, there is considerable word-specific and dialectal variance:<sup>1 2 3 12</sup>

- ***club***
  [clu   ~ clup] <sub>(general)</sub>
  [clup ~ cluβ] <sub>(educated, bilingual, and English-familiar speakers)<sup>4</sup></sub>
- ***pub***
  [pu ~ puf] <sub>(Nativised pronunciation based on orthography)</sub>
  [paf]      <sub>(Emulation of English pronunciation /pʌb/)</sub>

#### Pronunciation of word-final /v/

All of the cited examples are of words originally ending "-b" /b/, or "-v" /f/, but I can find no loanwords in Spanish where the source word ends in /v/ and the Spanish word also ends on a consonant.<sup>9</sup> However, among L2 English speakers word-final /v/ is often reduced to [f].<sup>3 5 6</sup>

#### NERV and Neon Genesis Evangelion's new dubs

Given *NERV* is a proper noun in a scripted context, the voice actors are likely emulating the Japanese pronunciation (or that of the German source-word) - which both end in unvoiced consonants - as is the case in the analogous new English dub:<sup>8</sup>

- `al` Nerv /nɛʁf/
- `ja` ネルフ /neɾɯɸɯ/

---

**Sources:**

<sup>1. [*Is there final devoicing in Spanish?*](http://seas3.elte.hu/VLlxx/barkanyi.html)</sup> 
<sup>2. [*Spanish phonology*](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/12999), 4.2 (p.44)</sup>
<sup>3. [*Production and Perception of Voicing Contrasts in English Word-Final Obstruents...*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237309236_Production_and_Perception_of_Voicing_Contrasts_in_English_Word-Final_Obstruents_Assessing_the_Effects_of_Experience_and_Starting_Age), 2.2 Materials (p.209)</sup>
<sup>4. [*Pidgin Traits in the Adaptation Process of Spanish Anglicisms*](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/112489.pdf) (p.242)</sup>
<sup>5. [*Chicano English: An ethnic contact dialect*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_Ns4VzgkyXcC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=spanish+devoicing+word+final+"/v/"), 3. Devoicing of *v* in Word-final Position (p.42)</sup>
<sup>7. [*The Sounds of Spanish*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=FUCRR4c-KuMC&q=pub), 8.2.4 Syllable-final plosives (p.146-148)</sup>
<sup>10. *Sound Pattern of Russian*, Halle</sup>
<sup>11. [*Manual de pronunciación española*](https://archive.org/details/manualdepronunci00navauoft/page/134), Navarro Tomás (1961) (p.134)</sup>
<sup>12. [*El plural de los anglicismos en español actual. Panorama y revisión crítica*](http://revistas.rae.es/brae/article/view/188/433)</sup>

**Notes:**

<sup>6. The pronunciation of a non-native phoneme by an approximation ("v" /v/ > /f/) can also be seen in certain loanwords e.g. [*hámster*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=h%C3%A1mster) ("h" /h/ > /x/).</sup>
<sup>8. In the original English dub, NERV is consistently pronounced like "nerve" /nɜrv/, but in Netflix's new English dub it is often pronounced like "nerf" (/nɜrf/ ~ /neɪrf/). Similarly with SEELE.</sup>
<sup>9. Note that *lev* y *molotov* themselves are pronounced /lɛf/ (лев) and [ˈmolətəf] (Мо́лотов) in Bulgarian and Russian respectively. Word final /v/ is generally devoiced in Russian unless the next word begins with a voiced obstruent.<sup>10</sup></sup>
<sup>Similarly for [*leitmotiv*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/leitmotiv-leitmotiv.636046/).</sup>

Comment: And even then, /d/ is often devoiced in speech (hence *Madriz*)

Comment: https://archive.org/details/manualdepronunci00navauoft/page/134

Comment: Identity constraints and Spanish resyllabification* , Sonia Colina

Answer (score 4):

Os pongo por aquí, para que conste, la respuesta que me ha dado la RAE a través de Enclave:

> La presencia de la uve en posición implosiva (esto es, a final de sílaba) no es patrimonial en español. De hecho, los términos que la presentan son, bien extranjerismos, bien acrónimos asimismo de procedencia extranjera: *leitmotiv*, *lev*, *molotov*, *ovni*. La conciencia que tiene el hablante de que tales términos son extranjeros favorece la labiodentalización que usted menciona. En todo caso, como se ve, la realización labiodental se halla muy restringida y no es distintiva, de modo que los tratados de fonética y fonología hispánica ni siquiera la recogen.

Parece pues que admiten que esa *v* a final de palabra o sílaba sí tiene una cierta tendencia a ser pronunciada parecido a *f*, pero al ser extranjerismos y en número tan reducido ni se molestan en comentarlo como caso particular.

Comment: Bueno, *ovni* no es un acrónimo de procedencia extranjera :) Pero vamos, se entiende la idea general.

Comment: *Ovni* se pronuncia, en mi experiencia, tal como debería esperarse: ['oβni], con el mismo comienzo que *obnubilado*.

Comment: Cómo dice Gorpik *ovni* no es extranjera y yo al menos, la pronunció como se escribe, al contrario que *molotov* o *leitmotiv*

Answer (score 2):

Molotov y Lev se pronuncian en Español exactamente igual a Molotob o Leb. Es la regla de pronunciación y no se cambia sin importar dónde se ubican. Como bien dices, en Español no existe la diferencia entre b y v.

Como decía el dicho latino:

> Beati Hispani, quibus bibere vivere est («Afortunados los hispanos, para quienes beber es vivir»)

Comment: Me parece óbvio y claro. No veo porque se haría de eso una pergunta académica.

Answer (score 0):

My instinct tells me that the OP's assumption is right and that the series is making a sort of a soft compromise, by making a tiny adjustment to the normal pronunciation of the v, to allow for the sort-of-Germanic pronunciation of the v (which sounds almost identical to the Spanish F).

@ukemi, what about Spanish words that end in "b", such as baobab, or in "z"?  They're all voiced.  Furthermore, I've been speaking Spanish my whole life (my mother tongue), in Buenos Aires, Argentina, and I don't pronounce or know anyone who pronounces voiced consonants at the end of a word as a p.  Never have I heard anyone say "clup" for "club", or "kebap" for "kebab" (although I do see it written like that here in Switzerland).

Comment: Ferk, it would be helpful to know what your regional variant is.  (I have heard a final V pronounced like P, in Puebla, Mexico.)

Comment: That's fair: I was born and raised in Buenos Aires, Argentina.

Comment: 1) There are less than 20 words ending 'b' in Spanish recognised by the RAE, and they're exclusively loanwords. 2) [z] *is* an alophone of /s/ (and [ð] of /θ/ etc) in Spanish, but only when occurring before a voiced consonant (e.g. *rasgo*, *jazmín*), and thus never word terminally. 3) I wouldn't extrapolate from fluent English speakers (e.g. yourself or @walen ) being able to pronounce English sounds without issue, that it is the usual pronunciation among Spanish speakers in general: http://seas3.elte.hu/VLlxx/barkanyi.html

Comment: @walen true, not a great source, I used it as it explicitly mentioned the same examples (and for the book it itself cites, which notes that the pronunciation [b] is generally seen among *more educated* speakers), the relevant citations in my answer cite more robust studies. But you're correct that this is a more subtle issue than I implied. Will update my comments, thanks.

Comment: Anything ending in v like that, as in molotov, would come out as a b in Spanish. I mean....There is no adjustment. There is just the only pronunciation it can have in Spanish, a /b/.