# ¿"Suscriptor" o "subscriptor" con "b"?

Tags: ortografía

Estaba redactando un email y escribí la palabra *subscriptor*. Me sonó muy mal, así que le quité la *b* para dejarlo en *suscriptor*. Pero siguió pareciéndome extraño.

Para más inri, el DLE menciona incluso dos más: *suscritor* y *subscritor* (sin la *p* antes de la *t*):

> [**suscriptor, ra**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=suscriptor)
>
> También. [subscriptor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YZC1vRd), [suscritor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Yoq1wOt), [subscritor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YZHbUYT).
>   `Del lat. subscriptor, -ōris.`
>
> 1. m. y f. Persona que suscribe o se suscribe.

¿Cuál es la forma recomendada de escribirlo?

Comment: https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/suscriptor-subscriptor-1368/

Comment: jajaja alguien voto para cerrarla porque "questions that show no effort".!!!

Comment: @DGaleano - Fui yo.  La misma persona encontró la respuesta, después de poner esfuerzo.  Ambos posts se redactaron hace 10 horas.  Si no fuera fedorqui, se hubiera aceptado esta pregunta?

Comment: @aparente001 yo creo que si porque la misma persona hace la pregunta **y la respuesta** por lo que la razón *"no effort"* no aplica. Ahora, si la pregunta fuera realmente off-topic por no pertenecer a este stack creo que si se debería borrar venga de quien venga. (+5-1) votos en la pregunta y 6 en la respuesta confirman que a muchos les parece interesante (Nota. yo no he votado en ninguna de las dos)

Comment: @DGaleano - Charlie, por ejemplo, tiene un montón de preguntas auto-contestadas, pero por lo que yo he visto, él hace un esfuerzo de demostrar por dónde sus indagaciones quedaron sin solución; y luego, si topa con una respuesta y la postea, se puede apreciar su carácter de respuesta buscada pero a veces un tanto accidental.  Ejemplo: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30782/9385

Comment: @aparente001 yo tengo bastantes respuestas a mis propias preguntas desde hace bastante tiempo ([dice SEDE que 18](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1073293/questions-that-are-self-answered-by-own-user?UserId=1674)). Intento seguir lo descrito en [What about adding general questions for reference?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2457/1674) para crear contenido útil para el sitio. Votar negativo y para cerrar no resulta demasiado acogedor... En cualquier caso, le he puesto un poco más de chicha para que no se diga.

Comment: @aparente001 En StackExchange las preguntas autorrespondidas son bien recibidas. Consulta [Can I answer my own question?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) hasta el punto de que te dan la medalla de _self-Learner_. El objetivo es **traer contenido útil al sitio**. Una cosa es que una pregunta muestre poco esfuerzo y el OP espere que otros hagan el trabajo extra y otra que, tras hacer ese esfuerzo extra, el OP responda su propia pregunta y quiera traer el contenido aquí. Con ese voto desanimas un poco a que otros usuarios traigan contenido interesante que se han encontrado

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Según explica el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas en su artículo *suscribir(se)*, **ambas son correctas pero *suscriptor* es más recomendable**:

> [**suscribir(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=YalBRyg1vD6P4JPpRe). 1. ‘Firmar [un escrito]’, ‘compartir [la opinión] de alguien’ y, como pronominal, ‘abonarse a algo’. Esta voz y todas las de su familia léxica pueden escribirse de dos formas: conservando el grupo consonántico etimológico -bs- (*subscribir, subscripción, subscriptor*) o simplificando el grupo en *-s-* (*suscribir, suscripción, suscriptor*). **Se recomiendan las grafías simplificadas**, por ser más acordes con la articulación real de estas palabras y las más extendidas en el uso actual.

Como se ve en el DLE, también son válidas tanto *suscritor* como *subscritor* (sin *p* antes de la *t*). Lo curioso es que *suscritor* no sea la preferida, pues sería la que más *simplificada* tendría la grafía.

Comment: Subscribir,  murciegalo, vagamundo ... todas correctas de punto de vista etimológico, pero a la RAE no le gustan

Answer (score 2):

La forma *suscriptor* es la más común hoy en día:

[image]

La forma [*suscritor*](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=subscriptor,suscriptor,suscritor,subscritor) suele usar en México, Venezuela y Colombia.

La forma [*subscritor*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subscritor) es la ortografía usual en portugués y gallego.

Comment: Es interesante el pico de _suscritor_ hacia finales del siglo XIX. Es la forma más simplificada pero por algún motivo ha ido perdiendo peso respecto _suscriptor_, que apenas se usaba por entonces. Dicho lo cual, parece que ninguna de ellas tiene demasiado uso actual.

Comment: No es cierto que suscritor se use en Mx, Vz y Co. Esto es una mala interpretación de la última gráfica del enlace Si se hace _drill down_ sobre Co en la primer gráfica se ve que siempre se usa **suscriptor** y la información para *suscritor* es tan marginal que no es posible generar las gráficas (claramente errores de digitación y no uso real) [ver aquí](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&geo=CO&q=subscriptor,suscriptor,suscritor,subscritor)